# Entity Framework Group By Then Order By

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm generating a query using Entity Framework which uses a group by clause and then attempts to order each of the groups to get specific data.  I attempted to optimize the order by to only happen once using a let statement but the results are incorrect but the query still executes.

Concept:

```
var results = 
(from n in noteEntities.NoteLog
where associatedIDs.Contains(n.AssociatedID)
group n by n.AssociatedID into gn
let ogn = gn.OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedDateTime)
let successNote = ogn.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "Success")
let lastStatusNote = ogn.FirstOrDefault()
select new { Success = successNote, Status = lastStatusNote, AssociatedID = gn.Key }).ToList();
```

However, the problem is that using, what should be the ordered let variable, `ogn` in the subsequent let statements is not using an order by descending list and I'm getting the wrong success and status notes.  I've also tried changing things up to create a sub-query and reference the result but that doesn't seem to return an ordered list either, ex:

```
var subQuery = 
(from n in noteEntities.NoteLog
where associatedIDs.Contains(n.AssociatedID)
group n by n.AssociatedID into gn
select gn.OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedDateTime));

var results = 
(from s in subQuery
let successNote = s.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "Success")
let lastStatusNote = s.FirstOrDefault()
select new { Success = successNote, Status = lastStatusNote }).ToList();
```

I can make this work by using OrderByDescending twice in the select statement or let statements for the success and status notes but this becomes very slow, and redundant, when there are a lot of notes.  Is there a way to run the order by only once and get the right results back?

Comment: did you ever figure this out

Answer (score 0):

In SQL a subquery with `Order By` *must* have a TOP statement (yours does not). And when Linq detects that there is no `FirstOrDefault` or `Take`statements with the ordered subquery it just strips the `OrderByDescending`.
If you are having a performance problem with the query perhaps you should look into indexing the table.